# C# Using Same Form

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, messagebox

I have a problem when we open FormA and FormB or others at the same time with below code. Codes :

```
namespace form_sample
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form SampleForm;
```

`public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void CreateForm()
    {
        SampleForm = new Form();
        SampleForm.Name = "formname";
        SampleForm.Text = "Form Caption";
        SampleForm.Show();
        SampleForm.Shown += new EventHandler(SampleForm_Shown);
    }

    private void SampleForm_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetElements();
        GetButtons();
    }

    private void GetElements()
    {
        TextBox textdata = new TextBox();
        textdata.Name = "TextData";
        textdata.Width = 200;
        textdata.Height = 50;
        textdata.Location = new Point(20, 20);
        SampleForm.Controls.Add(textdata);
    }

    private void GetButtons()
    {
        Button ShowMsg = new Button();
        ShowMsg.Name = "ShowMsg";
        ShowMsg.Text = "Show TextBox Message";
        ShowMsg.Width = 100;
        ShowMsg.Location = new Point(100, 100);
        SampleForm.Controls.Add(ShowMsg);
        ShowMsg.Click += new EventHandler(ShowMsg_click);
    }

    private void ShowMsg_click (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Control elements in SampleForm.Controls)
        {
            if (elements.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
            {
                MessageBox.Show(elements.Text.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    private void FormA_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CreateForm();
    }

    private void FormB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CreateForm();
    }

    private void FormC_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CreateForm();
    }

    private void FormD_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CreateForm();
    }

    private void FormE_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CreateForm();
    }
}`

}

For Ex : FormA and FormB and FormC are open. And I want to display FormC's TextBox Message.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the issue that you show the form *before* you wire the Shown event?

Comment: It's not really clear what the problem is.  Can you describe it?  Also note that every time you call `CreateForm` you overwrite the reference to the previous form, which probably isn't what you want.

Comment: All the form are showing normally. It's working fine. But when we open the all form (A,B,C,D,E forms), we can not reach textbox value

Comment: These codes are sample. Our main purpose is to open all forms at the same time, and to show FormC TextBox.Text with the MessageBox.

Comment: Move the declaration of textData to the form level.  Now you can just update it: `textDate.Text = "Hello"`.  Note though, your code is heading toward spaghetti-ville.  It's not clear why your parent form is the one creating the textbox in the second form.  Those details should happen in the second form's code base.

Comment: In fact, I have asked [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32980660/using-same-created-winforms-for-adding-and-editing) with detailed but I could not received any reply. So, I have prepared a little project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `SampleForm` field always contains the last form that you have created, that's why using it from inside the events produces incorrect behavior.
To fix that, first remove the `SampleForm` field from your `Form1` class. Then use the following modified versions of your methods:

```
private static void CreateForm()
{
    var SampleForm = new Form();
    SampleForm.Name = "formname";
    SampleForm.Text = "Form Caption";
    SampleForm.Show();
    SampleForm.Shown += new EventHandler(SampleForm_Shown);
}

private static void SampleForm_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var SampleForm = (Form)sender;
    GetElements(SampleForm);
    GetButtons(SampleForm);
}

private static void GetElements(Form SampleForm)
{
    TextBox textdata = new TextBox();
    textdata.Name = "TextData";
    textdata.Width = 200;
    textdata.Height = 50;
    textdata.Location = new Point(20, 20);
    SampleForm.Controls.Add(textdata);
}

private static void GetButtons(Form SampleForm)
{
    Button ShowMsg = new Button();
    ShowMsg.Name = "ShowMsg";
    ShowMsg.Text = "Show TextBox Message";
    ShowMsg.Width = 100;
    ShowMsg.Location = new Point(100, 100);
    SampleForm.Controls.Add(ShowMsg);
    ShowMsg.Click += new EventHandler(ShowMsg_click);
}

private static void ShowMsg_click (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var ShowMsg = (Button)sender;
    var SampleForm = ShowMsg.FindForm();
    foreach (Control elements in SampleForm.Controls)
    {
        if (elements.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(elements.Text.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I've made all these methods `static`, so there is no way to make a mistake referencing a shared variable. To make the things easier to understand, I kept your names although they are not following the recommended C# naming conventions.

Comment: Ivan, thanks so much. In fact, I could not understand logically. :) GetButtons(Form SampleForm). I have solved my problem. Again thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

You're only ever holding a reference to *one* form:

```
public Form SampleForm;
```

And you keep overwriting that reference every time you make a new form:

```
SampleForm = new Form();
```

So any time you make a new form, you can no longer access the previous forms.  They're still open, but this code doesn't hold a reference to them.

There are a number of different ways to address this and to architect your code.  The *simplest* and most immediate would be to be consistent with the rest of your code.  Note that the ret of you code explicitly assumes a finite set of specific forms:

```
private void FormA_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CreateForm();
}

private void FormB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CreateForm();
}

// etc...
```

So you might as well stick with that pattern, at least for the time being to get this working.  (Refactor later.)  To do that, create a finite set of variables to hold references to your forms:

```
public Form SampleFormA;
public Form SampleFormB;
public Form SampleFormC;
public Form SampleFormD;
public Form SampleFormE;
```

Then modify your function to accept a reference to the form being created:

```
private void CreateForm(Form form)
{
    form = new Form();
    form.Name = "formname";
    form.Text = "Form Caption";
    form.Show();
    form.Shown += new EventHandler(SampleForm_Shown);
}
```

And add that reference to the invocations of that function:

```
private void FormA_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CreateForm(SampleFormA);
}

// etc.
```

**(By now I'm sure you can start to see patterns emerging in all of this repeated code.  This is where you start to think about refactoring.  I'm intentionally leaving this as an exercise for you to consider and focusing only on the cause of the error at hand.  But let's just finish making it work first...)**

Following this same effort, your other functions are also going to need to be given references to the specific forms they want:

```
private void GetElements(Form form)
{
    // use the function variable instead of the class variable
}

private void GetButtons(Form form)
{
    // use the function variable instead of the class variable
}
```

To supply that reference to those functions, use the objects available to your event handler:

```
private void SampleForm_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GetElements(sender as Form);
    GetButtons(sender as Form);
}
```

You can certainly put in some error checking there to make sure `sender` is indeed an instance of `Form`, that there isn't some other error in system state, etc.  But this *should* get you going at least.

Your other events will likely need similar changes.

Ultimately, the problem is that you're trying to do everything from a single variable.  But you have multiple instances of forms.  So you need variables for all of them (or a collection/array/etc. in a single variable... remember to think about refactoring to remove repeated code) and the functions which act on them need to be more dynamic, rather than all acting on a single variable.

Comment: I am trying to understand your declaration clearly. But I could not it. For ex : I do not know how many forms will be created. I have given only 5 forms. These forms' name are getting from the Sql data Store. May be it will be 5 forms, may be 100 forms. How can I give a reference???

Comment: @Aydin: That's where you're going to want to start using dynamic collections, such as a `List<Form>`, instead of a finite set of variables.  This is going to end up modifying your entire structure, particularly your finite set of buttons that you currently have.  There's another answer posted which may help you get started on that.  Essentially a collection (such as a `List<>`) can hold a variable number of elements and you can refer to items within the collection.

Answer (score 0):

```
public Form SampleForm;
private void CreateForm()
{
   SampleForm = new Form();
   ...
}
```

Every time you call CreateForm() you lose the ability to get the form that was stored in that variable before.

A simple correction would be to use a pattern like this

```
 public List<Form> SampleForms = new List<Form>();
    private void CreateForm()
    {
       var form = new Form();
       SampleForms.Add(form);
       ...
    }

//use this to get a form from the collection. Form.ID, Form.Text
private Form GetForm(string formName)
{
   return SampleForms.FirstOrDefault(f => f.ID.Equals(formName));
}
```